# os.rename [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I tried to rename directories in MacOS, even have used codes of others but `os.rename` still throws me errors, I give the full path of my directories and their new names as `path`. May someone help to solve this problem? thanks in advance

```
import os

directory = "/../"
dirs = next(os.walk(directory))[1]
for file in dirs:
    path = os.path.join(directory, file)
    target = os.path.join(directory, '/' + file.replace('.','/'))
    os.rename(path, target)
```

with dash

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Kakadu/Desktop/dogs_vs_cel/MsCelebV1/MsCelebV1-Faces/m.01kk_s6' -> '/m/01kk_s6'
```

without dash

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Kakadu/Desktop/dogs_vs_cel/MsCelebV1/MsCelebV1-Faces/m.01kk_s6' -> '/Users/Kakadu/Desktop/dogs_vs_cel/MsCelebV1/MsCelebV1-Faces/m/01kk_s6'
```

P.S file exists and os.rename works when I do rename the file to the same name

```
 target = os.path.join(directory, file)
 os.rename(path, target)
```

And by the way, I'm trying to rename the directories(full of images) inside the directory, maybe something is in here.Btw, when I try just to use os.rename on images ( not on directories full of images  ) it works fine

Comment: check manually that your file really exists

Comment: Yes, I have done all these things

Comment: add an `if` to test if they are equal

Comment: case sensitivity issue maybe?

Answer (score 1):

When renaming something to /j/k/l/m/foo, it is important that [directory m exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs). If not, you must mkdir m.

Just before your rename call, do this:

```
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(target), exist_ok=True)
```